# How to add default header fields from http.Client

Tags: go

I want `http.Client` to add additional header for all requests.

```
type MyClient struct {
    http.Client
}

func (c *MyClient) Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "go")
    return c.Client.Do(req)
}
```

`func Do` never gets called if I call `func PostForm` that is using `Do`. If there is no way how to mimic OOP, how to do it least painfully?

Comment: It depends on your purpose and design. On this specific one, you can set a custom Transport which is a field of `http.Client` and can add headers there.

Comment: Could you please give me a hint how to add headers with Transport?

Comment: _"If there is no way how to mimic OOP, how to do it least painfully?"_ <-- can't help but respond to this: Golang isn't meant to be used in classical OOP way, so please don't even try to mimic typical OOP constructs. It's easier just to learn to use the language in the way it was intended to be used, rather than to force it to behave in ways it was not

Comment: Still would be great to have this feature to be able to change composited methods like in OOP, but must be reasons that Go designers haven't done this feature. Maybe in future this will be implemented?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`http.Client` has a field `Transport` which is of type `RoundTripper` - an interface type.

It provides us the option to change request (and response, of course) between.

You can create a custom type that wraps another `RoundTripper` and adds the header in the custom type's `RoundTrip`:

```
type AddHeaderTransport struct{
    T http.RoundTripper
}

func (adt *AddHeaderTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response,error) {
    req.Header.Add("User-Agent", "go")
    return adt.T.RoundTrip(req)
}
```

Full code on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/FbkpFlyFCm_F

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#RoundTripper
Why does it recommend to not modify the request here?

Comment: Google breaks their own recommendation in this exact way to support OAuth 2.0 so I would take that recommendation with a grain of salt. It does look like a bit of messing around with cloning and closing, so be prepared for weirdness. https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/oauth2/+/refs/tags/v0.4.0:transport.go;l=51

Comment: Google doesn't exactly break the recommendation, in that link you shared it is actually cloning the request, so it's not modifying the original one.